# Porque o Vagrant não esta sincronizando as pastas?

Tags: ruby, windows, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

Estou usando:

```
Windows 8 64 bits    
Vagrant 1.7.2
Virtual box 4.3.28
GitBash 1.9.4 para conexão SSH
Box Ubuntu 14.04.02 Trusty 32 bits
Box Ubuntu 14.04.02 Trusty 64 bits
```

Estou desenvolvendo com Ruby on Rails, porem não consigo editar os arquivos gerados na box, a pasta vagrant não está sincronizando nem lendo os arquivos no meu diretório de projetos.

Segue meu vagrant file:

```
  # -*- mode: ruby -*-
  # vi: set ft=ruby :

  # All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
  # configures the configuration version (we support older styles for 
  # backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
  # you're doing.
  Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "trusty64"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
  # such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
  # config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
  #   push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   sudo apt-get update
  #   sudo apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL
 end
```

Alguém sabe porquê?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu resolvi o problema usando uma outra box que encontrei no vagrantcloud.
Primeiro configurei no Mac, após tudo funcionando, gerei uma box (package) e passei pro windows8, fiz o procedimento normal e funcionou!

Eu recomento que use sistemas 64bits, sistemas 32bits não suporta nfs, e habilite a virtualização na bios.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que "descomentar" a linha referente ao compartilhamento de pastas.

```
config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"
```

O primeiro parâmetro é a pasta do seu host, o segundo é do guest (VM - Vagrant). Você vai ver que na sua VM tem uma pasta na raiz chamada vagrant. Recomendo que os seus arquivos ou pastas compartilhadas fiquem lá (foi o único lugar que funcionou comigo). Se você tentar compartilhar a pasta home o vangrant vai exigir senha.

Lá na documentação tem alguns parâmetros a mais... dá uma olhada lá:
https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html

Answer (score -1):

É só descomentar a linha:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"
```